# WCF and code generation from WSDL

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I am writing a "universal" client for Web services, and have hit an unexpected problem. I generate the code for the client dynamically by retrieving the Web services WSDL, and using the following (simplified a little) code to generate the client code:

```
ServiceDescription serviceDescription = ServiceDescription.Read(xmlTextReader(WSDL));
ServiceDescriptionImporter descriptionImporter = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();
descriptionImporter.ProtocolName = "Soap";
descriptionImporter.Style = ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client;
CodeCompileUnit codeCompileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
CodeDomProvider codeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
codeDomProvider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(codeCompileUnit, Console.Out, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
```

I am testing this using a simple WCF Web service that exposes two methods:

```
[OperationContract]
int GetInteger();

[OperationContract]
string GetString();
```

If I examine the client-side generated code, then I can see that the GetString() returns a string, but the GetInteger() method returns void! I assume that this is something to do with value and reference types. Is there some way to force the code generator to make the GetInteger() method return an int?

Comment: In C# 'int' type is a primitive , whereas the 'Integer' type is an object, try using 'Integer'. (string is an alias for System.String. So technically there is no difference. Thats why your GetString() method returns string)

Comment: I was under the impression that you can't pass integers using SOAP and WCF architecture but I might be wrong

Comment: Hi - thanks for your comments. I don't think that there is an Integer type in C#, is there? However, more importantly, I'd like my client application to work against any Web service (the one I created is just a simple test one), and so I have to allow for the possibility that Web services have methods as I describe above.

Answer (score 2):

Returning an int over WCF should not be a problem.

Check the code that produces the client side generated code.

The hack to get around the problem would be to return an object that had a single property that was an int.

Comment: The code that generates the client-side code is all standard C# classes (see above). I may be misusing one of the classes or is there maybe a flag I can set to get an int returned?

Comment: Check the WSDL file, is the return type void in the WSDL file?

Comment: Hi - no, as far as I can tell both return types are what you would expect:

    `<xs:element name="GetIntegerResponse">  
      <xs:complexType>  
        <xs:sequence>  
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="GetIntegerResult" type="xs:int"/>  
        </xs:sequence>  
      </xs:complexType>  
    </xs:element>  

    <xs:element name="GetStringResponse">  
      <xs:complexType>  
        <xs:sequence>  
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="GetStringResult" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>  
        </xs:sequence>  
      </xs:complexType>  
    </xs:element>`

Answer (score 0):

From various experiments, I believe that my problem is an inherent limitation of using the ServiceDescriptionImporter to generate the client code. I am going to try to "upgrade" to using the System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlImporter and System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceContractGenerator framework, in the hopes that improves things.